# SQLAlchemy: A filter property that variably validates against different tables?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a web app that needs to consolidate several tables into a single User class. The problem is that certain users will need to be linked to one table and others to another. This is a general view of how my models are set up.

```
class User(Model):
    IDType1 = Column(Integer())
    IDType2 = Column(Integer())
    Active = Column(Boolean())
    #...

class OtherType1(Model):
    ID = Column(Integer())
    Active = Column(Boolean())
    #...

class OtherType2(Model):
    ID = Column(Integer())
    Active = Column(Boolean())
    #...
```

Each OtherType has a flag marking them as active or inactive and it's updated with relative frequency. I want to be able to check if the User is active which in turns means I have to variably check if their respective flag is marked as active. Ideally I'd like to perform the query below but I don't know if that's possible.

```
query = User.query.filter(User.is_active==True)
```

The best option I can think of is to have a method called active_users which creates a basic Query with the Join/Where statements in place but I'm curious if there's a better way.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the [`Model.query.filter_by`](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/queries.html#querying-records) method for this.

So your query would be something like:

```
User.query.filter_by(Active=True)
```

Comment: The problem with filter_by is that it doesn't check the columns in the other tables. I want it to check OtherType1.Active if User.IDType1 is not NULL or check OtherType2.Active if User.IDType2 is not NULL.

Comment: @JBolton Well, that's not what's apparently been asked. Please consider editing it. Please add that comment in your question.